# C#: How to consume StreamContent via REST Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, multipartform-data

**Task:**

I am trying to send the image from the C# client at the C# Http Server. The image is stored in the memory only and should not be stored on any hard drive.

**State:**

I have C# client (.NET FW 4.5) sending an Http request on C# MVC API Controller, using MultiPartFormDataContent.

The client minimal code:

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("R:\\a.png", FileMode.Open));

using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
  form.Add(content, "img");
          
  var post = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:58652/api/bubla", form);
  var resp = post.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I am trying to consume the stream on the server-side using:

```
[Route("api/bubla")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post([FromForm] MultipartFormDataContent content)
  {
    // ???
    // e.g. :
    // var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("R:\\temp");
    // await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    // not working
  }
}
```

**Issue:**

I have no idea how to consume the data at the server-side. I have read many tutorials, most of them requiring `Request.Content` which I do not have. The server-side code above will provide 'something' in the `content` variable, but I have no idea how to read it out.

**Additional notes:**

For the final solution, the image cannot be stored on the hard drive - only memory streams. (The reading from the disc in the code above is for the illustration only.

Maybe I am doing something generally wrong